# reading facility code and card number in a HID iClass card

Tags: python, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc, contactless-smartcard

I am reading an HID iCLass card using the Rfidiot library with an Omnikey 5427 CK reader in Python. I can get the UID which is for example (79 FE C1 00 FB FF 12), I also used the Omnikey Workbench to get it and they matched. However, if I enable the Keyboard Wedge mode, I get 79fec100fbff12e0007130da84, which includes the UID + facility code + CN.

I need to be able to read the same result without the keyboard wedge mode but can't find any way to do it. I have tried to find a APDU command but couldn't find anything related.

Does anyone experience with this kind of cards?

Comment: That reader works as a CCID compliant, just turn off keyboard wedge mode and use the PC/SC APIs to communicate with the card.  These APIs are available on Windows and Linux and OS/X platforms.  Python has a library for working with PC/SC it may even be called pycard.

Comment: Can you please share your source code . I want to make the same for android or using python